# FIND command not listing files defined in -mtime

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to find all the .log files in my defined directory that are older than 10 days old but when I compare the finding of my find command and what is in the directory there are specific files not being picked up by the find command.  Any help/direction would be appreciated. I've looked all over Stackoverflow to find an answer but cannot find one that meets my issue.

Today's date/time is:  01/29/2015 14:33:00

Command I'm using is:

```
find /var/log/app/*.log -type f -mtime +10 ! -name 'Verification1.log'
```

When I looked at the list of files this command finds I did not see in the list this file:

File Name:        file.log
Date Modified:    1/18/2015 5:59 PM

Why would this file not be picked up in my list of files if -mtime works on a 24 hour period?  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-mtime +10` means more than 10 days old.  However, `find` does not count fractions.  So, for example, the output would included files that are 11 or 12 days old *but not* files that are 10.9 days old.

Consider

> Today's date/time is: 01/29/2015 14:33:00

With `-mtime +10`, only files older than 01/18/2015 14:33:00 would be included.  Consequently, your file dated `1/18/2015 5:59 PM` is not included because `5:59pm` is after, not before, `14:33:00`.

#### Documentation

The integer but not fraction method of comparison for days is specified in `man find`:

```
   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how round‐
          ing affects the interpretation of file modification times.

   -atime n
          File was last accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file
          was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to  have  been
          accessed at least two days ago.
```